# Show the same mouse cursor in two different windows OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working with OpenCV (for C ++). I am showing the three channels of an image in three different windows at the same time. I would like to know if there's a way to show the same cursor in all of them. I mean, I would like to have three cursors (one in each window) and all of them synchronized with the movements I do in the main window.
Thank you very much,

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Get the mouse coords in the first window and use the opencv drawing commands draw a crosshair on the other two

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to do (using circle instead of a crosshair), but I need a fast way to erase it in order not to have all the itinerary drawn

Comment: OK now I made it work using this approach. I created another function taking care of this and now everything works fine. Thank you!